# Menu ativo na página selecionada no Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, menu

Olá,

Estou utilizando o tema Constructzine Lite do repositório do Wordpress. Pois estou com dificuldade em deixar o menu ativo quando estou em uma página específica.

Alguém pode me ajudar?

link tema: https://wordpress.org/themes/constructzine-lite

Obrigado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvido!

Apenas editei a classe current_page_item no css ficando:

```css
.navigation-menu li.current_page_item a { 
   background: #000;
   color: #fff;
}
```